# What library can I use to pick images from Google in my web app?

Tags: javascript, image, lightbox

I am creating a web app, part of which requires people add "experiences" to a list. These might include foods to eat, places to go, sights to see, etc. I want people to be able to add their own event to a list and have an image associated with them.

I find that when people have to locate their own image from the web, download it, and then upload it to another site, it's too much effort and they won't do it. Therefore I think people should be able to choose an image from a Google search within my app, and select and image which the app then uses as the image for that "experience". I know this can be done using the Google search API, and you can specify only public domain images, so that there's no legal ramifications of using images from Google.

I imagine this is quite a common thing for websites to do. I thought I would be able to find a Javascript library that launches a lightbox over the top of a page and allows a search and selection of an image, but I can't seem to find one. Does anyone know of any such library, or anything similar?

Alternatively, is there some obvious way around this issue that someone has seen? What is a good way to avoid the "upload image" process for a website, but still have image-enriched content? I'm sure there's something obvious I'm overlooking here.

Thanks!

Comment: i think the better way is to support drag and drop and let them drop their selection from the image search where they want it. (well, its just an option but i do agree that this is less integrated than a light box would be)

Answer (score 0):

The now deprecated Image API was one starting point to do it, however you still have to implement the lightbox ... https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/

Be careful when you are looking at using the image search results! apart from (possible) copyright issues also make sure that you have permission from Google to do automated requests against them.